# Why there is no problem with Uri.fromFile even in android:targetSdkVersion = "25"?

Tags: android

In an Android application,

I've heard I'm not supposed to use `Uri.fromFile` for `targetSdkVersion >= 24` as following link:

[Here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en)

But I use it without any crash under the following conditions:

> android:targetSdkVersion = "25" , 
>   Android Nougat

```
 else if (requestCode > Constants.Uri_M4_Images_Camera_Filter)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {

                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                Uri_M4_ViewPager_M4Image_Camera = Uri.fromFile(saveImage2(photo));
```

I can use `Uri_M4_ViewPager_M4Image_Camera` in Picasso with no problem, Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `Uri.fromFile()` is in passing that `Uri` to another app in an `Intent`. That will trigger a `FileUriExposedException`. Even if you hack your way around it, on Android 10+, the other app will not have access to the file anyway.

Using `Uri.fromFile()` within your own app usually is unnecessary. Picasso, for example, can work with a `File`; you do not need to convert one into a `Uri` just to have Picasso convert it back. However, if you really want to use a `file` `Uri` inside your own app, you are welcome to do so. Just do not pass it to another app.